# java - get files and subdirectory only of a particular directory level

Tags: java

Having a Path, how can I list all files/subdirectories of a particular depth level?

Using find(...) from java.nio.file.Files I can specify maxDepth not the depth I want to search.

I could use the matcher in find() to filter the files based on the depth level but I don't know how to create this matcher.

In general having 2 paths how can I know if one is a "sub-path" and its depth level related to the other path?

Thanks

Comment: have a look at `java.io.File.getParentFile()`, it allows you to split the path into its components.

Comment: How is `maxDepth` 'not the depth I want to search'?

Comment: @EJP with, for example, maxDepth = 2 it will search in depth level 0,1 and 2. In my case I just want to search in the level I specify. for example just level 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
      if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
      }
    }
```

It allows you to go inside folder, but if you want to go up one level do:

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
    File parentFolder = folder.getParentFile();
```